# Android: Any Ideas on how to make a Hearthstone/Magicka type of card?

Tags: android

Details:
I was wondering how to create an object in android that has multiple layers of graphical elements. A good example would be a Magicka or Hearthstone card. They have 3 elements: the background of the card, the image of the creature, text describing something + stats.

The idea behind this is to have fewer images that can be put together to create a great amount of cards. I should mention that in my case the background card and the creature are vectors (SVG).

How do you put all of these elements together in one card-thing that can later be displayed&animated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use proper layout.
Most reasonable to me is using `RelativeLayout`.

You can put all views:

- background (can be a separate view or `background` view param)
- image (ImageView)
- text (TextView)

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:background="@color/aaa">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cat_filmy_main" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Movie Killer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the effect is:
[image]

Also, consider creating your own view. How to do that can be found here:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-custom-views--mobile-14548

Comment: Didn't think of that, nice! Thank you!